# Ruby changing true and false values in hash through string input

Tags: input, hash

Learning Ruby from square one.

I would like to try to change the value of a hash, by matching the key with user input.

for example

```
list = {
   "records" => false,
   "games" => false,
   "phones" => true
}

action = gets.strip
```

I could be wayyy off, but I'm assuming that I need an "if" statement that might start something like:

```
if list.include?(action)
```

but not really sure.
so if the user types "records" the statement becomes true.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks pretty hacky, and the best advice probably is “this should be done differently”. But, lacking time, this should work:

```
list.keys.each { |k| list[k] = (action == k) }
```

Update, because you wanted something different:

```
list[action] = true
```

Comment: why "k" in the pipes? Is that short for key?

Comment: Yes, it’s just a generic variable name. Any other would do as well. Ruby 2.7 also sets some parameter automatically, but I keep forgetting what it’s called. Something like .each {  list[_1]. or @1 would also work

Comment: This is great thank you. but my bad for not explaining, this seems to  flips some of the other values. It there a way to only flip the one value the user inputs that matches a key?

Comment: amazing. that is very cool and word. If did a second "if "statement to go the other way would it go the other way (changing true to false), but in your opinion is there a way to do it with one statement? Thank you for your time.